# Can I use serialize on a PHP variable?

Tags: php, serialization

Is it correct?

```
$date_range = serialize($test_pack_type_id);
```

If yes, then what's the use of this?

```
if($key == 1) 
              $date_range = array('from_date'=>$form_data['registered_users_from_date'], 'to_date'=>$form_data['registered_users_to_date']);
            else if($key == 2) 
              $date_range = array('from_date'=>$form_data['logged_in_users_from_date'], 'to_date'=>$form_data['logged_in_users_to_date']);
            else if($key == 3) 
              $date_range = array('from_date'=>$form_data['not_logged_in_users_from_date'], 'to_date'=>$form_data['not_logged_in_users_to_date']);
            else if($key == 3)
              $date_range = $test_pack_type_id;
```

Actually all are arrays that I'm assigning to the `$date_range` variable. But the last variable, i.e `$test_pack_id` is a simple variable. I want to insert these files into a database.

Comment: Is there a question here that isn't answered by looking in the manual? http://php.net/serialize If there is, can you elaborate?

Comment: For your reference I'm adding my extra code to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be packing an array containing the elements `from_date` and `to_date` into one database column.

While `serialize()` is an okay way to do this, it isn't really good from a database architecture point of view. Are you sure you will never need from_date and to_date in a query? Because for any kind of sane use inside the database, you should definitely have two separate columns for each value. That would also help for any kind of filtering/sorting.

Answer (score 1):

`serialize` is used to turn any complex data structure into a string, so it can be stored in a file, database, cookie, etc. or transmitted over the network.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that some objects, for example PDO class instances explicitly forbid serialization. For more information you can check out __wakeup(), __sleep() magic methods and Serializable interface.

Answer (score 0):

`serialize()` can be used on any type (except resources).
The purpose of serialization usually is to be able to save it (persistence).